# Display custom name on control instead of variable name in ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm

I've a DataGrid like this:

```
 <DataGrid 
      x:Name="TotalMatch" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding TotalMatch}"/>
```

I'm using the ViewModel pattern, so in my property I've created in this case an ObservableCollection that store the data. This collection have the structure of TotalMatch:

```
public class TotalMatch
{
    public int InPlay { get; set; }
    public int Terminated { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}
```

Now the DataGrid column are displayed as the variable name, so: InPlay, Terminated and so on..

I'm wondering if is possible display instead of the variable name a custom name. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Pharoah is right - there's a few standard column types you can use, the simplest being DataGridTextColumn. So you might end up with:

```
 <DataGrid 
      x:Name="TotalMatch" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding TotalMatchCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="In Play" Binding="{Binding Path=InPlay}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Terminated" Binding="{Binding Path=Terminated}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="The Total" Binding="{Binding Path=Total}" />
</DataGrid>
```

I'm a bit surprised by your binding though - you look to be setting the ItemSource to a single element in your ObservableCollection, whereas you'd normally set it to the entire collection. So I took a punt and changed the ItemsSource in that snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide custom names to the columns, there are properties like HeaderText in Datagrid that lets you select the Column name, but you will have to bind each column individually using DataColumn control.